# Retrofit - How to convert Response to HashMap?

Tags: android, hashmap, gson, retrofit

I have a question about Android development using Retrofit by Square.
Let's say I have a Response object which is actually a `HashMap<String, String>` object.

Is there a way to get a `HashMap` object from this Retrofit object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Response` object contains various information about response returned from the server.

If you mean that response body is `HashMap` you can either parse the body when `success()` is called, or register type adapter when build your `RestAdapter` and write deserializer that will parse and populate the `HashMap`.

```
 private RestAdapter getRestAdapter(){
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType(), new MyHashMapDeserializer());
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
        builder.setClient(new OkClient());
        builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
        builder.setExecutors(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), new MainThreadExecutor());
        builder.setConverter(new GsonConverter(gsonBuilder.create()));
        builder.setEndpoint(API_END_POINT_URL);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Then create new class (or inner class) that will `implements JsonDeserializer<HashMap<String, String>>` and implement your deserialization logic.

Make sure you adapt `K,V` types to your needs.

Comment: Gson will deserialize a `Map` without any configuration. So you really don't have to do any of this, just specify a `Map` as your Retrofit return type or `Callback` type.

Comment: This above comment should be the answer !

Answer (score 0):

@Jake Wharton says:
Gson will deserialize a Map without any configuration. So you really don't have to do any of this.

just specify a `Map` as your Retrofit return type or Callback type.